# Set current params to ui-sref

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to send the current item `id` from the url to each state from ui-sref in navigation:

index.html:

```
<body ng-controller="mainController as main" class="animated fadeIn">
    <!-- Working Group Header -->
    <div ng-include=" './partials/navigation.html' "></div>

    <!-- Routes -->
    <ui-view></ui-view>
</body>
```

navigation.html:

```
<ul >
    <li>
        <a title="About" ui-sref="about({id: id})">About</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a title="Files" ui-sref="files({id: id})">Files</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a title="Demos" ui-sref="demos({id: id})">Demos</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

My routing looks like this:

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $compileProvider) {
    //FOR UNMATCHED URL, REDIRECT TO HOME
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('about')

    // Set up routes
    $stateProvider
        .state('about', {
            url: '/wg/{id}/about',
            templateUrl: './partials/about.html',
            controller: 'aboutController'
        })
        .state('files', {
            url: '/wg/{id}/files',
            templateUrl: './partials/files.html',
            controller: 'filesController'
        })
        .state('demos', {
            url: '/wg/{id}/demos',
            templateUrl: './partials/demos.html',
            controller: 'demosController'
        })

   $compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(false);
})
```

MainController:

```
    wg.controller('mainController', function($scope, $timeout, $stateParams){
    console.log('Entered home controller ')

    $scope.id = $stateParams.id;

})
```

My URL:

> index.html#/wg/123/about

However, when I check the url I get back i

> index.html#/wg//about

Answer (score 0):

In the `$stateProvider` defination you need to change the syntax of param from `{id}` to `:id`. Then the `id` should be accessible to controller using `$stateParams.id` after injecting `$stateParams`.

```
$stateProvider
        .state('about', {
            url: '/wg/:id/about',
            templateUrl: './partials/about.html',
            controller: 'aboutController'
        })
        .state('files', {
            url: '/wg/:id/files',
            templateUrl: './partials/files.html',
            controller: 'filesController'
        })
        .state('demos', {
            url: '/wg/:id/demos',
            templateUrl: './partials/demos.html',
            controller: 'demosController'
        })
```

Controller Example:

```
.controller('demosController', ['$scope','$stateParams',function($scope, $stateParams) {
   $scope.id = $stateParams.id;  // <------ id now should be available in the child route controller
});
```

Comment: Do I need to do `$scope.id = $stateParams.id` for each controller? That seems pretty inefficient considering it's the same `ID` for each view. Also I tried what you suggested but my nav is still not picking up the `id` param

Comment: No you can do it in the parent controller depending on how your controllers are inherited. It should still work the same way. Its hard to specify where for me though because you only have partial dom in the question.

Comment: I've tried doing it in my main controller but the url still returns `/wg//about` with the missing id. I've cleaned up the OP

Comment: That makes it a little more clear. Now if you read the id in individual children controller is it accessible?  I suspect that your main controller is already loaded the way you have setup before you click on links. So only option for you would be to maintain the ID in each of the children controller. Its not so bad to repeat that. Think about it, you parent controller cannot know the what state/id the child is going to be initialized in. It can also change dynamically.

Comment: Yes but navigation.html isn't part of the children. It's part of the mainController. So setting the ID in the other controllers wouldn't help.